# How do I make my application using Mongodb and nodejs HIPAA compliant?

Tags: mongodb, security, hipaa, database

I am writing an application to be used potentially by doctors to keep in notes about patients (my app is not targeted for doctors but other professions don't need such strict rules).

My app is written in nodejs and only the backend can access the database with an authenticated user account and following all common security practices such as firewall rules etc.

I read about HIPAA compliance but most of them don't apply because no user specifically has access to the database unless it's coming from the API of the backend for which of course you need to authenticate against my app with SSL.

How can I be confident that doctors can use my app? Is there any authentication test/certificate etc?

Comment: The HIPAA  requirements apply to the entire software stack, not just the database. A friend of mine wrote the software for point of sale terminals for the pharmacy of a major department store chain.  Because of HIPAA,  they couldn't use off the shelf POS software in the pharmacy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mongodb website has a great example of Hippa compliance standard,I think the following will help you:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/making-hipaa-compliant-applications-mongodb

Comment: That article is only for MongoDB Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

AWS based applications can be made HIPAA compliant by referring the following detailed documentation of AWS https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-compliance/ 
There is a nicely written whitepaper by AWS available at the above mentioned link